# Select items of list of strings that contain certain characters

Tags: r

I' ve got a list of names.

```
l1 <- rep(paste("Session", 1:6, sep=""), each=4)
l2 <- rep(paste("ID", 1:4, sep=""), 6)
list <- paste(l1, l2, sep="")
```

With real data the list is far more complicated ;)
How do create a new list from this list, that includes only those items from Session 1-4?

In dplyr there is the >>select(contains("Session1"|"Session2"))<< which is used to select variables in data.frames.
I am looking for something similar to use for lists.

Comment: what you have shared is a vector and not a list .

Comment: just a comment on naming: avoid using names which are reserved for functions, especially something as common as `list`. it makes debugging difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want ?

```
list[grepl("Session(1|2|3|4)ID", list)]
[1] "Session1ID1" "Session1ID2" "Session1ID3" "Session1ID4" "Session2ID1" "Session2ID2" "Session2ID3" "Session2ID4"
[9] "Session3ID1" "Session3ID2" "Session3ID3" "Session3ID4" "Session4ID1" "Session4ID2" "Session4ID3" "Session4ID4"
```

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg this one?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option with regex lookarounds to match "Session" followed by numbers 1-4 and not followed by any number (`(?![0-9])`)

```
grep("Session[1-4](?![0-9])", c(list, "Session10ID"), value = TRUE, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Session1ID1" "Session1ID2" "Session1ID3" "Session1ID4" "Session2ID1" "Session2ID2" "Session2ID3" "Session2ID4" "Session3ID1" "Session3ID2"
#[11] "Session3ID3" "Session3ID4" "Session4ID1" "Session4ID2" "Session4ID3" "Session4ID4"
```